# How serve web-folder in Spring Boot out from /resources/

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, web, directory

I need help, my Spring Boot 2 Server from a first web generate other web site (folder with html,css ext ext) from a template, but these web sites/html aren't accessible, Spring give me error 404, not found.

I will build the project with Maven in .jar

The gerarchy of the project is this:

```
---
 |_folder (Directory with webapps generated, NOT DELIVERED)
 . |_webapp1
 . |_webapp2
 |_src
 . |_main
 . . |_java
 . . |_resources
 . . . |_public (With first web)
 . . . |_static (Template used to generate other web site, i simply copy this directoy in other directory, doing  templateServices.copyDirectory("target/classes/static/", "folder/webapp1");
---
```

I tried with this configuration, but dont work.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class StaticResourceConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    private static final String[] CLASSPATH_RESOURCE_LOCATIONS = {
            "classpath:/META-INF/resources/", "classpath:/resources/",
            "classpath:/static/", "classpath:/public/", FileController.uploadingDir};

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/**")
                .addResourceLocations(CLASSPATH_RESOURCE_LOCATIONS);
    }
}
```

Comment: could you show some code please?

Comment: About what? Thanks so much for your support

Comment: ah, you have no code. At least explain properly what you're trying to do? You have a Spring Boot App that generates a static website in the `public` directory, and then you want to be able to deliver that website from the same app creating those sites?

Comment: The jar with Spring Boot 2 have to deliver the first website from where users generate other websites. The jar generate "folder" with all these website generated in public static final String uploadingDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");

Comment: I havent code to deliver the website generated, the configuration of Spring boot is default, i tried addResourceHandlers, but nothing, tomcat embedded dont deliver these new webapp. I post this code up.

Comment: @MagdKudama The Server dont generate the webapps in public directory, but in "folder"

Comment: @D.Corra Maybe you need to add templateResolver for thymeleaf configuration. I just worked before thymeleaf can you check this link https://github.com/haticeSigirci/camp/blob/master/src/main/java/tr/org/lkd/lyk2015/camp/config/WebConfig.java ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the web server is going to generate websites, as you said, then you should save the files outside the Spring Boot scope; just in a folder of your filesystem. An example could be:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class AppConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
  @Override
  public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry
        .addResourceHandler("/**")
        .addResourceLocations("file:/var/www/websites/");
  }
}
```

If you have dynamic websites (you said it depends on the users) you can inside the method get all users in the system, and add ResourceHandlers for them in specific locations.

Comment: I did the same, check my code in first post, but dont work.

Comment: Can be thymeleaf the problem? Because is enabled.

Comment: Look at my example, the prefix is `file:`, not `classpath:`. I just gave it a try, and it's working just fine. Of course, if you have to parse Tymeleaf templates and do some extra processing, you'll need a different strategy to present the websites. I thought you really were generating static HTML files?

Comment: I debbugged , and the string i generate is "file:C:\\Users\\username\\IdeaProjects\\transfer/folder/", its ok? Maybe this is the problem.  I generate a web app with a specific html that take the files uploaded from the user, putted in specific folder with the same name. For now im trying to fix this problem coping the .html not personalized.

Comment: it's not correct, no. For windows it'd be: `file:///C:/Users/username/IdeaProjects/transfer/folder/`. Try that!

Comment: There is a method to format the user.dir path in this format ( C:\\Users\\username\\IdeaProjects\\transfer/folder/ ). Thanks so much.